# Word for something that can't be smelled?

Tags: single-word-requests

An invisible thing can't be seen, but what do you call something which cannot be smelled?

Comment: For all five: invisible, silent, tasteless, odorless, intangible.

Comment: @PeterShor Or if you want to stick to more parallel words (negated with _in-_): invisible, inaudible, ingustable, inodorous, intangible. Can't find a proper _-ble_ parallel for smell, unfortunately.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Someone later suggested 'inolfactible' for my question, so that would match your set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inolfactible. Olfactible is in the O.E.D.

Comment: This is very rare.

Comment: @Mitch Rare yes, but I feel it matches more with "visible" than the other suggestions. It's both specific to the sense of smell and connotates  more of the absence of sense itself than just the object's inert quality.

Answer (score 6):

**odourless**

An odour is a smell.

Comment: ***Inodorous***  :  odourless; having no odour. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/inodorous

Answer (score 2):

You'd need some context to make this work, but I rather like

**imperceptible**

(meaning that something can't be perceived by the senses or a sensor)

Answer (score 0):

***Tea? Soap?***

*unscented,* means it hasn't had any scent added.

***Shirts? Socks?***

*clean,* means they're recently washed.

***Pebbles? Chemicals?***

*inert,* means it's unreactive and won't stimulate those nerve-endings.

***inert*  [(Merriam-Webster)](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inert)**

> 3 :  deficient in active properties; especially :  lacking a usual or
>   anticipated chemical or biological action

***Forensic specimen?***

*odourless,* (odorless) free of odour

Comment: You can still generally smell unscented tea and soap, as well as pebbles and clean socks, though. They're not _odourless_ as such.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet,  well, it's comparative. People will continue to be congratulated that their socks don't smell. Others will continue to lament that a new rose has no smell. Ultimately it was music that Auden claimed was  "invisible...and does not smell." Any others?