# Is there an olfactory counterpart to quiet?

Tags: single-word-requests

I would describe a faint sound as being quiet, and recently I wished to express the idea of quietness for smells.  I wanted a word like faint but specific to smells (or smells and tastes if such does exist).  An example sentence might be

> *This tarmac is _____ after the rain*

Does such a word exist?

[This](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/272305/word-for-something-that-cant-be-smelled) similar question asks about things that have *no smell at all*.  While similar I am seeking to describe something that does have a smell albiet a faint one.

Comment: Google has failed me thus far. The closest I have come is [_hyposmia_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyposmia), but this refers to weakness of the smeller's sense, rather than weakness of the smell itself. Moreover, I can't find any evidence of an adjectival form.

Comment: With smells you need to be more specific; e.g. with food you can use words like *aroma*. Verbs like *waft* are helpful, including with perfumes. Not sure about tarmac though. What is it that smells? Is it a vapour? You could perhaps say something like "With a faint waft of tarmac vapour caressing one's nostrils..."

Comment: @WS2 Hm.  I've never heard waft used as a noun, but it seems that it is, however the usage in my dictionary suggests a slightly different use than the one you provide.  Thanks for the response though.  Gives me something to think about.

Comment: A faint odor could be called a whiff.

Comment: @Xanne I'm more familiar with a whiff meaning a *short* smell as opposed to a faint one.  For example if I opened a jar of rancid beans and quickly closed it I might say *Wow! That was some whiff right there*.  Perhaps both senses are valid and context disambiguates the two.

Comment: Are you trying to say something like, "This tarmac *gives off **a hint of** <something>* after the rain"?

Comment: As it stands, "quiet" means *silent or nearly silent* and the equivalent would be *odorless or nearly odorless*.

Comment: Bland, insipid or unstimulating could work, but they're not specific to smells (could be fine if its a phrase not SWR)

Comment: You already used the work you're looking for: *faint: (of a sight, smell, or sound) barely perceptible.*

Comment: If you don't need literal meaning and just need to play with the "strength" of the word [Unscented](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unscented) might be an option (although it literally means "no scent" or "odorless"). I would interpret it as: "Smells less than it should".

Comment: A perfume with an odor that is not intense, or food with flavor that is not intense, are sometimes described as *subtle* or *delicate*.

Answer (score 3):

This tarmac is *faintly odorous* after the rain.

This tarmac is *faintly scented* after the rain.

Answer (score 0):

It's not elegant, but:

**[deodorised/deodorized](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/deodorize?s=t)**

1. to rid of odor, especially of unpleasant odor.

It really depends on your interpretation of the *de-* prefix. Does it infer an absolute removal of the odor, or merely a reduction/inhibition of it?

Answer (score -3):

'Petrichor' is a word for the smell of the earth after a rain. Perhaps a derivative or similar of that may help.

Comment: I'm not really concerned with Tarmac.  That's just an example.  Moreover the smell of petrichor actually comes from plants not the earth and doesn't really smell much like wet tarmac.

Comment: Both tarmac and concrete are good repositories of petrichor (geosmin), which is released by rain.  If you want a faint peaceful smell, try snow.